# Ошибка в боте telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
import telebot
import random
from telebot import types
sl='E:\telegrambot\1.jpg'
sk ={
    '1':'текст1',
    '2':'текст2',
    '3':'текст3',
    '4':'текст4',
    '5':'текст5',
    '6':'текст6',
    '7':'текст7',
    '8':'текст8',
    '9':'текст9'        
}
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN');
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'yes':
            bot.send_photo(messege.chat.id, open(sl))
        elif call.data == 'no':
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.id, text= sk[str(random.randint(1,9))])  
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Пишет ошибку     bot.send_photo(messege.chat.id, open(sl))
NameError: name 'messege' is not defined

Comment: у вас не правильно написано, поменяйте на message, и еще + вы уже вошли в callback, поэтому перед message напишите call, должно получиться call.message.chat.id

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в функцию в качестве аргумента вы передаете не message, а call. Нужно написать так:

```
bot.send_photo(call.chat.id, open(sl))
```

Либо поменять аргумент с call на message.

Comment: bot.send_photo(call.chat.id, open(sl))
AttributeError: 'CallbackQuery' object has no attribute 'chat' теперь это пишет

Comment: @user476966 в таком случае попробуйте call.message.chat.id

Comment: когда вы используете в боте call то после него идет message( в данном случае) без него будет выдавать ошибку